# How to pass a parameter of array/collection type at Jaspersoft Studio and use it at query?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm trying to pass as a parameter, an array of values to get a report from my DW, using an "IN" clause.

The problem is that, when I set the parameter as "Array" or "Collection", it don't prompt on Jaspersoft Studio Preview screen, and I can't use it.

The first time, I've tried to pass the parameter as a String, where $P{convenio} was a string, passed to complete "IN":

```
//Select and joins here...
WHERE ("o"."status_operacao" IN ('EFETUADO', 'SUSPENSO'))
  AND ("c"."codigo" IN ( $P{convenio}))
  AND ("o"."codigo_produto" = 1)
```

It doesn't worked, returning an error "missing EOF at ')'", but there's no error of closure.

The last option was using $X{}, so I've set de $P{convenio}, as an Array/Collection type, and turned the query like this:

```
//Select and joins here...
WHERE ("o"."status_operacao" IN ('EFETUADO', 'SUSPENSO'))
  AND ($X{IN, "c"."codigo", convenio})
  AND ("o"."codigo_produto" = 1)
```

But now the param isn't prompting, and the report brings me everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*JasperReports* engine supportes nested types - we can use typed collections.

#### Show collection at JSS - using dialog to set value

For example we can declare parameter of *Collection* type like this:

```
<parameter name="collectionParam" class="java.util.Collection" nestedType="java.lang.Long"/>
```

Small example of report with typed Collection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="collectionParam" class="java.util.Collection" nestedType="java.lang.Long"/>
    <title>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="550" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{collectionParam} != null && !$P{collectionParam}.isEmpty() ? $P{collectionParam}.toArray()[0] : "empty"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

We can initialize collection at *Jaspersoft Studio* (*JSS*) like this:

1st step - calling parameter dialog:

[image: Set parameter at JSS]

2nd step - adding element to the *Collection*:

[image: Add new element at JSS]

We can check (build) report via Preview action:

[image: Preview at JSS]

- as a result we are showing first element of *Collection* with help of expression:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{collectionParam} != null && !$P{collectionParam}.isEmpty() ? $P{collectionParam}.toArray()[0] : "empty"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

#### Initializing parameter of Collection type using default value expression

We can initialize parameter of *Collection* type with help of defaultValueExpression and for example with *[java.util.Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))* method:

```
<parameter name="collectionParam" class="java.util.Collection">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[java.util.Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

#### Using at query

The parameter of *Collection* type can be used at query with help of `$X{IN, <column_name>, <parameter_name>}` expression.

Example:

```
<parameter name="param" class="java.util.Collection">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[java.util.Arrays.asList("val")]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM table_name c WHERE $X{IN, c.attr, param}
</queryString>
```

This expression will be transformed at runtime by *JasperReports* engine into query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name c WHERE c.attr IN ('val')
```

We can also use parameter of *String* type at query in couple with ***IN*** operator using`$P!{}` expression.

Example:

```
<parameter name="param" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["'val1', 'val2'"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM table_name c WHERE c.attr2 IN ($P!{param})
</queryString>
```

This expression will be transformed at runtime by *JasperReports* engine into query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name c WHERE c.attr2 IN ('val1', 'val2')
```

Comment: Passing like SELECT * FROM table_name c WHERE c.attr2 IN ($P!{param}) as recommended worked for me. Thx

Comment: IN ($P!{param})  not working in new jasper versions anymore